Styles and Colors not working in .NET MAUI after migration from Xamarin.Forms
I have an Xamarin.Forms application migrating and I have a problem with the styles that are working in the Xamarin.Forms. When the app starts I have an Init() function which merge all the resource dictionaries like this:
 private static void Init(ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary)
 {
     resourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(new LabelStyles());
     resourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(new FrameStyles());
     resourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ButtonStyles());
 }

Did I miss maybe a build action, or some other configuration? At the moment, only the colors and styles are not working. I also don't see any error in the output.
Does anyone else have a similar problem?
P.S. The default Styles.xaml and Colors.xaml from .NET MAUI are working  and all the styles are working perfectly fine in Xamarin.Forms.
Update : Problem with the colors was related to the type System.Drawing.Color. Created a converter and that part is fixed. But still got a problem with the styles.

Where did you put the Init method? In addition, did you try to merge the resourcedictionay in the app.xaml?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT I call it in my Startup.Configure() in App.xaml.cs.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT areSystem.Drawing.Colors supported in .NET MAUI and can be used?

for instance BackgroundColor property is of type Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color. not sure if System.Drawing.Colors is supported but i believe you should stick with maui's type. related discussion

Also one think that I do for test was adding the styles in Styles.xaml. Everything worked fine.

The api System.Drawing.Colors can be used in the Maui, but you can't set it as the maui control's color property.
As Cfun said: the maui control's color property is type of Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color. If you set the value as System.Drawing.Colors, you will get error about type can't convert.
But you can convert the System.Drawing.Colors to Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color, such as:
public Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color ConvertColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    return Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromRgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
}

In addition, I suggest you use the Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color directly and merge the ResourceDictionary in the app.xaml or just add the styles into the default Styles.xaml.

Thank you for the suggest. Yes for Colors I created a converter and use it everywhere, but for the styles I have other components(nuget packages) and in there I have the resources for the styles and in there I receive  ResourceDictionary from the app and I merge all the necessary styles. And because of that I cant add them directly in the App.xaml.
